# Windows Phone 8.1 Don't Allow App to Rotate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I don't want my app to rotate when the user flips the phone. It should stay in portrait orientation. I don't have other rotations supported in the `.appxmanifest`, so why would it still rotate? How would I tell it not to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

> DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences =
>   DisplayOrientations.Portrait;

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted.